# PHP Problems with download

Tags: php, iis, content-disposition

My php files are downloading instead of showing. I know my problem. The problem is with the PHP download. I am using php with IIS. When I uninstall php, the php code just shows as code, and it doesn't interpret the text. When I download php, it downloads the file and doesnt show it entirely. I dont know if i messed up with my settings when downloading it, but i just used the default that it gave me. Ive tried using different downloading settings, but they don't seem to help.

Comment: Do you have to use IIS? Or could you use something like WAMP?

Comment: Did you install PHP from here - http://php.iis.net/? Should be fairly straight forward